# How to change the position of the trackbar in OpenCV applications?

Tags: c++, opencv

Usually in my OpenCV projects, after creating a trackbar and placing it in a window, it appears horizontally and at the bottom of the window.

**Is it possible to change the trackbar's position and orientation?**

Comment: you probably can't, without hacking the implementation (which also differs by os/gui toolkit used). also, on win, trackbars will appear on top of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unfortunately no**, [`cv::createTrackbar()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#createtrackbar) doesn't allow changing the position and orientation of the trackbar.

But if you have Qt installed you can create your own GUI, [with the trackbar (QSlider) you want](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-sliders.html). You just need to learn to [convert a `cv::Mat` into a `QImage`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5026965/176769)