# How to specify width and position of a trackbar in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to specify the size and the postion of my trackbar. With the following code the trackbars are as wide as my window, and they are under each other.

```
cv2.namedWindow('Settings')

cv2.createTrackbar('A', 'Settings', 0, maxA, startlinechanged)
cv2.createTrackbar('B', 'Settings', 0, maxB, endlinechanged)
cv2.createTrackbar('C', 'Settings', 0, maxC, distancechanged)
cv2.imshow('Settings', img)
```

How can I specify the width and the position of the trackbars? I would like to put their to the bottom of the window (under the image) and next to each other. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27570946/4980722

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no. Trackbars are always fixed at the top of your window. I have been looking for the same for a while.

Comment: Not quite true. On my systems running opencv-python 4.6, Trackbars are at the top in Windows10 and macOS 13, but in Ubuntu Linux 20.04, they are at the bottom.