# OpenCV and QT compiling errors

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

i've installed OpenCV 2.4.5 for QT 5.0.2.I 've spent about whole week to set the paths and libraries but every compiling is without success.The problem is that QT does not give me the real amount of errors -> they are changing every time (1,13,2,4).At the beginning i 've got only 2 error messages about cv::mat::setFree(void *) and cv::mat::deallocate() errors.I 've made video for my problem in youtube and i will post it here.Please help me however you can.I really need your help cause i am getting deeper and i can't do anything.If you help me, you will help to lot other guys with the exact same problem.The only thing i know is that, i have some mistake in the LIBS and INCLUDEPATHS.
However watch the video and thanks to all in advance.
PS: I am on windows 7

Video - > http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cW_3Wj74xLM

Other thing to say is that i've tried including all the libraries [ALL] from OpenCv and that was stupid but it didn't solve my problem too. -.-

Comment: Please confirm that the tags provided are correct.

Comment: Can you paste the part of your .pro file where you add the libs? At least your program compile with gcc and find the OpenCV libraries?

Comment: INCLUDEPATH += D:\\ProgramFiles\\OpenCv243\\build\\include
INCLUDEPATH += D:\\ProgramFiles\\OpenCv243\\build\\x86\vc9\\lib


LIBS += -LD:\\ProgramFiles\OpenCv243\build\x86\vc9\lib \
   -lopencv_calib3d243 \
   -lopencv_contrib243 \
   -lopencv_core243 \
   -lopencv_features2d243 \
   -lopencv_flann243 \
   -lopencv_gpu243 \
   -lopencv_imgproc243\
   -lopencv_legacy243 \
   -lopencv_ml243 \
   -lopencv_nonfree243\
   -lopencv_objdetect243 \
   -lopencv_photo243 \
   -lopencv_stitching243 \
   -lopencv_ts243 \
   -lopencv_video243 \
   -lopencv_videostab243

Comment: You have installed OpenCV version 2.4.5, right? In the .pro file, I noticed that you are trying to load the libraries from version 2.4.3. Try to change to the correct version and see if it works.

Comment: Take a look on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881913/how-to-link-opencv-in-qtcreator-and-use-qt-library

Comment: Actually, with all the versions is the same work, same errors.The link that you've sent, i think it will solve my problem, but now i will go sleep cause here in Bulgaria the hour is 01:27am and i am trying to solve this for about 11 hours.I need some rest.Thank you for everything.I will check what will happen tomorrow and i will write here again.Bye ;)

Comment: After this day, my problem with the camera was totally solved.There are no more problems.Now i will continue my GUI project thanks to all of you guys.After 1-2 months i will start searching for how to write printer driver ;), but however.Thanks too all again. ;)