# Error in OpenCV configuration for Qt Creator

Tags: qt, opencv, cmake

I followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881913/how-to-link-opencv-in-qtcreator-and-use-qt-library) instructions in the configuration of OpenCV SDK for using it in Qt Creator IDE, but I couldn't conclude point 6.5, due to configuration errors in Cmake-GUI. I setup the configuration in CMake of the compilers gcc and g++ contained in Qt folder for MinGW32, and all looks Ok. But when Cmake-GUI starts the process of build configuration it ends up saying

> "Error in configuration process, project files may be invalid".

It can't find the following:

> - QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE;
> - Qt5Concurrent_DIR;
> - QT5Core_DIR;
> - QT5Gui_DIR;
> - QT5Test_DIR;
> - QT5Widgets_DIR.

After this issue I tried to go on with following points of configuration tutorial, without reaching the final instruction of mingw32-make install. I'm using the following versions of softwares: Qt 5.3.0, OpenCV 2.4.9, CMake 2.8.12.2. My OS is Windows 7.

How can I recover the missing Qt files in CMake configuration?
Is there an alternative way for configuring OpenCV with Qt (like using precompiled build of OpenCV libraries)?

Comment: How is CMake called? Have you passed the QT5Core_DIR?

Comment: I just tried to locate the files manually into the QT folders, now I'm waiting the result of mingw32-make instruction on cmd prompt... and then mingw32-make install has to work, this last step never worked before. I'll post soon the result.

Comment: It's ok, it is working now!

Comment: Great, does this include running "make install" from your old original question? I created an answer below, please accept it.

Comment: Yes, I concluded the whole configuration, now openCV works with QT Creator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the location of Qt manually by passing it as an argument for `QT5Core_DIR`. `Qt5_DIR` or `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` does also the trick.

Example
Given your Qt 5 is installed at `/opt/selfcompiled/Qt5`. When calling `cmake`, add the flag from above:

```
cmake -DQt5_DIR=/opt/selfcompiled/Qt5 <pathToSourceDir>
```

Once the Qt 5 directory is set and found by CMake, all the other variables related to Qt 5 should be found from there, too.

Comment: This answer is not precise enough. Please specify the steps needed.

Answer (score 8):

You just need to indicate CMake the correct paths to each one. Click oh the path to browse and set each one individually:

- QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE;
   For this one, you need to search inside the Qt installation folder for the /bin directory. On it, you' ll find the **qmake.exe**. In my case it was **C:/Qt/5.3/winrt_x64/bin/qmake.exe**

  All the following ones are in the Qt's /lib/cmake directory. In my case: **C:/Qt/5.3/winrt_x64/lib/cmake** :
- Qt5Concurrent_DIR;
  C:/Qt/5.3/winrt_x64/lib/cmake/Qt5Concurrent
- QT5Core_DIR;
  C:/Qt/5.3/winrt_x64/lib/cmake/Qt5Core
- QT5Gui_DIR;
  C:/Qt/5.3/winrt_x64/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui
- QT5Test_DIR;
  C:/Qt/5.3/winrt_x64/lib/cmake/Qt5Test
- QT5Widgets_DIR.
  C:/Qt/5.3/winrt_x64/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets

Then click generate. It' ll show a new error and ask you for the QT5OpenGL_DIR. Just as before, show CMake the correct directory. In my case: **C:/Qt/5.3/winrt_x64/lib/cmake/Qt5OpenGL**. Finally, click Configure again, and then Generate, and now you're done creating the build files.

Comment: thank you so much life-saver! this should be the accepted answer.