# Configuration incomplete error ocuured ,This message happened when I am trying to link qt with opencv using cmake

Tags: qt, opencv, cmake

I am trying to link OpenCV library with Qt (following [these instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csxkdGQQgNg)), but I have some compilation errors:

[image: Compilation errors]

Any one can help me?

Comment: Did you see the pic,All of what I need is a help to understand what is the source of this problem?and how can I solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the Paths by hand. Click on the red entries and set the path to the according path.

You can read more about this problem in this Question: [Error in OpenCV configuration for Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912319/error-in-opencv-configuration-for-qt-creator)

Comment: Thanks ,I follow the instructions on the link you've mentioned and It works fine ,the program works But I have another problem which is displaying image in screen using imshow() function , It display a white window http://pbrd.co/1qgNHIZ

Comment: Please open up a new Question. But, in short: check if your image was loaded correctly.

Comment: I have already opened a new question and it is solved
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25904628/can-not-read-image-in-opencv