# Qt - How to build a standalone app with OpenCV and Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, opencv, user-interface

I was able to connect `Qt`with `OpenCV` and the my application is working properly. But now would like that my `.exe` file does not have any dependencies with `.dll` files. I would like be able to use my application in another computer without concerns.

I tried to search in several [forums](https://qt-project.org/wiki/Build_Standalone_Qt_Application_for_Windows) but i didn´t find any solution to my problem.

Adding `CONFIG += static` to my `.pro` file is enough??

Comment: Did you already build Qt as a static library? Is this a commercial application? If so are you going to supply the object files so your customers can rebuild your application with a new static build of Qt?

Comment: @drescherjm I build `Qt` as a static library once, but when i did that `OpenCV` stop working with `Qt`. Then, with `Cmake`, i tried to build opencv with Qt [Stackoverflow Guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881913/how-to-link-opencv-in-qtcreator-and-use-qt-library). At the end of all this i reinstalled Qt and repeat the steps on the previous link, and it is working. I'm still not able to create files without any kind of `.dll` dependencies... (as a "standalone" version). This is a gui that i am developing for a course, there is no commercial purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `CONFIG += static` indeed, besides that you need to create a static build of OpenCV, Qt, and statically link it all into an exe.

I shared my setup [here](https://github.com/mamoit/qt-opencv-builder).

Just clone the repo and follow the instructions :)

Answer (score -1):

check out bin2h. it can convert your dll file to a header file that you import into your project. you can then write out to file the generated header and then dynamically link it to your executable