# Error compiling opencv with mingw in order to use it in QtCreator

Tags: qt, opencv, build, mingw

I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881913/how-to-link-opencv-in-qtcreator-and-use-qt-library) link to build opencv in order to use it with QtCreator, the procedure goes well unitl the invoking of `mingw32-make` command, which produce this error:

```
[  2%] Built target zlib
[  5%] Built target libtiff
[  9%] Built target libjpeg
[ 12%] Built target libjasper
[ 14%] Built target libpng
[ 20%] Built target IlmImf
[ 20%] Built target opencv_core_pch_dephelp
[ 20%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_core
[ 23%] Built target opencv_core
[ 24%] Built target opencv_ts_pch_dephelp
[ 24%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_ts
[ 25%] Automatic moc for target opencv_highgui
[ 25%] Built target opencv_highgui_automoc
[ 25%] Automatic moc for target opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp
[ 25%] Built target opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp_automoc
[ 25%] Built target opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp
[ 25%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_highgui
[ 26%] Built target opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp
[ 26%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_imgproc
[ 29%] Built target opencv_imgproc
Linking CXX shared library ..\..\bin\libopencv_highgui249d.dll
modules\highgui\CMakeFiles\opencv_highgui.dir\build.make:690: recipe for target 'bin/libopencv_highgui249d.dll' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:2026: recipe for target 'modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all' failed
makefile:136: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

I have tried with opencv 2.4.10 and 2.4.9 and I get the same error. I tried with cmake version 3.1.3 and 3.2.2 and nothig changes.
My Qt version is: Qt Creator 2.8.1 Based on Qt 5.1.1 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit).

Someone can suggest me something else to try?

Thanks

Comment: I am a little confused why you are using mingw and MSVC at the same time. Use 1 or the other for all dependencies.

Comment: Actually in QtCreator I can select between different compile "kit" (mingw or MSVC). I wrote "Qt Creator 2.8.1 Based on Qt 5.1.1 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit)" because is what i see under "help"->"About QtCreator" in QtCreator even if if select to compile with mingw