# Visual Studio with Qt Add-In linking to OpenCV

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I try to integrate the OpenCV library into my Qt-based project in Visual Studio 2012. I know there exist a lot of other threads to this problem but none solved my linking issues.
Here is my setup:

- Windiws 8.1 64-Bit
- Visual Studio 2012 32-Bit
- OpenCV 3.0
- Qt 5.1 32-Bit and Qt Add-In 1.2.3

I downloaded the OpenCV 3.0 Windows package and used CMake and the Visual Studio compiler to build it; I followed this [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881913/how-to-link-opencv-in-qtcreator-and-use-qt-library). The build folders look like this: [image]. The .lib and .dll files were generated correctly: [image] [image]
Then I followed the instruction on the official OpenCV [page](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html) and this [one](https://drthitirat.wordpress.com/2014/12/26/install-opencv-2-4-10-and-use-it-in-msvc-2013-and-qt-5-4-0-of-windows-8-1-64-bit-os-x64-based-processor/) and did the following configurations:

- **VC++ Directories ‣ "Executable Directories"**:   I added the path to the *bin* folder which is shown in the third picture
- **VC++ Directories ‣ "Library Directories"**:   I added the path to the *lib* folder shown in the second picture
- **C/C++ ‣ General ‣ "Additional Include Directories"**:   here I added the path to the original *include* folder of the extracted OpenCV package as the build *include*s folder is empty
- **Linker ‣ General ‣ "Additional Library Directories"**:   here I added the path to the lib files
- **Linker ‣ Input ‣ "Additional Dependencies"**:   here I listed all libraries like this:
  opencv_core300d.lib
  opencv_highgui300d.lib
  opencv_imgproc300d.lib
  opencv_video300d.lib
  opencv_calib3d300d.lib
  opencv_contrib300d.lib
  opencv_features2d300dd.lib
  opencv_flann300d.lib
  opencv_gpu249d.lib
  opencv_legacy300d.lib
  opencv_ml300d.lib
  opencv_nonfree300d.lib
  opencv_objdetect300dd.lib
  opencv_ocl300d.lib
  opencv_photo249d.lib
  opencv_stitching300d.lib
  opencv_superres300d.lib
  opencv_ts300d.lib
  opencv_videostab300d.lib

I also want to note that I can not change the code generation to */MTd* as Qt would not work with that (but that should not be the problem since I build OpenCV activating the option WITH_QT in the CMake configuration)

Additionally I put all .dll files in the same directory as my generated debug .exe (Visual Studio otherwise complained that the .dll could not be found)

When I try to execute a function of the OpenCV lib or only create an object I always get *unsolved link* errors like this one:

Fehler  2   error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""class cv::Mat __cdecl cv::imread(class cv::String const &,int)" (?imread@cv@@YA?AVMat@1@ABVString@1@H@Z)" in Funktion "_main".

or this one

Fehler  2   error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: __thiscall cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(void)" (??0VideoCapture@cv@@QAE@XZ)" in Funktion ""void __cdecl loadMovie(class QString)" (?loadMovie@@YAXVQString@@@Z)".

I really would appreciate the help since I have been struggling for one whole week now trying everything I found on the internet.

Comment: can you add the other libs too? e.g. opencv_videoio300d.lib ... since opencv3 there are some functionalities split from highgui to different libs. not sure where `imread` is placed now.

Comment: probably `opencv_imgcodecs300d.lib`

Comment: thank you for your quick response; I added opencv_imgproc300d.lib and opencv_imgcodecs300d.lib to the linker input and the link seems to be resolved.I try to include the other libraries not listed by the OpenCV documentation and try to get the _VideoCapture_ working. Hoepfully that will work; again I apperciate your quick answer.

Comment: very well written question btw, which makes quick answering possible without asking for additional information =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that the provided link `How to build applications with OpenCV inside the Microsoft Visual Studio` is for OpenCV 2.4.11 where libraries were managed a little bit different.

From OpenCV 3.0 on, opencv_highgui lib is split to different sub-libraries concerning VideoCapture, image reading and other stuff. As you can see in your screenshot, there are other libs, which you didn't add yet to your project, e.g. `opencv_imgcodecs300d.lib` and `opencv_videoio300d.lib`

Try to add all those libraries. If that works, and if you want to reduce dependencies, you can remove libraries until linker fails.