# OpenCV ImageStitching App working on Visual, not working with QTCreator. Code is the same in both

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2013, qt-creator

I have application made with QTCreator. It uses OpenCV 2.4.11. I have the same application on Visual. Code is the same in both.

OpenCV for Microsoft Visual 2013 was made using this link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e_TQ9c3n_d8

It is for 2.4.10, but it's the same for 2.4.11.

And I configured QtCreator with this tutorial:

[How to link opencv in QtCreator and use Qt library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881913/how-to-link-opencv-in-qtcreator-and-use-qt-library)

Now the code:

```
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include "opencv2\stitching\stitcher.hpp"
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
void ReadPhotos();

double begin_t, end_t;
int photo_number = 0;
Mat photos[100];
Mat image;
vector< Mat > ImagesVector;
vector<Mat> roisVector;

int main()
{
cout << "Starting program!" << endl;

ReadPhotos();

Size size(1050, 600);

for (int i = 0; i < photo_number; i++){
    //resize(photos[i], photos[i], size);
    ImagesVector.push_back(photos[i]);
}

Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault(true);

stitcher.setWarper(new SphericalWarper());
stitcher.setFeaturesFinder(new detail::SurfFeaturesFinder(300, 3, 4, 3, 4));
stitcher.setRegistrationResol(0.9);
stitcher.setSeamEstimationResol(0.9);
stitcher.setCompositingResol(1);
stitcher.setPanoConfidenceThresh(1);
stitcher.setWaveCorrection(true);
stitcher.setWaveCorrectKind(detail::WAVE_CORRECT_HORIZ);
stitcher.setFeaturesMatcher(new detail::BestOf2NearestMatcher(false, 0.3));
stitcher.setBundleAdjuster(new detail::BundleAdjusterRay());
Stitcher::Status status = Stitcher::ERR_NEED_MORE_IMGS;
try{
    status = stitcher.stitch(ImagesVector, image);
}
catch (cv::Exception e){}

imwrite("panorama.jpg", image);

waitKey(0);
return 0;
}

void ReadPhotos(){

string sourceIN;
string sourcePhoto;

sourceIN = "paths1.txt";
ifstream FileIN(sourceIN);

if (FileIN.is_open())
{
    while (getline(FileIN, sourcePhoto)){

        photos[photo_number] = imread(sourcePhoto, 1);
        photo_number++;
    }
}
else{
    cout << "Can't find file" << endl;
}

cout << "Number of photos: " << photo_number << endl;

}
```

Read photos function takes path to images from txt file and load photos.

In visual studio it's working good, I can stitch 3500x2000 resulution images and it gives nice output panorama. In QtCreator I try to stitch the same images and it gives following errors:

1. OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 290519044 bytes) in OutOfMemoryError, file C:\OpenCV2411\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp, line 52
   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
   what():  C:\OpenCV2411\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp:52: error: (-4) Failed to allocate 290519044 bytes in function OutOfMemoryError
2. Bad alloc - sorry, I can't make this error again so can't copy exactly.

Anyone has any idea why the same code is not working on QTCreator and is working in Visual Studio 2013? Library is the same. One thing I can think of is that I build libraries for QTCreator myself with Cmake. Maybe it has something with this.

Comment: Are you building a 64 bit application in QtCreator?

Comment: That could be it. I'm using 32bit QTCreator. I will check it :)