# Consistent build error for building opencv with qt option using CMake-gui

Tags: qt, opencv, cmake

### Highgui module build fails keeping appearing in the build process

Hi everyone, I've been quite frustrated and desperate to find the way to fix this really bizarre error about the task of linking OpenCV to QT SDK using CMake-gui. I've already tried to fix this problem for a week straight, but I kept having this following build error [Basically saying that opencv_highgui not be able to build its target with the QT option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiHCP.png).

[26%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp.cxx.obj

Linking CXX static library ....\lib\libopencv_highgui_pch_dephelpd.a

[ 26%] Built target opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp

[ 26%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_highgui_Debug.gch

[ 26%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_highgui

mingw32-make[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881913/how-to-link-opencv-in-qtcreator-and-use-qt-library): *** No rule to make target 'C:/opencv2.4.12/opencv/sources/modules/highgui/', needed by 'modules/highgui/qrc_window_QT.cpp'.  Stop.

CMakeFiles\Makefile2:1982: recipe for target 'modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all' failed

mingw32-make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiHCP.png): *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
makefile:145: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2

I was able to fix a bunch of major and minor issues for the configuration process, but couldn't get over this build error when compiling MinGW 32 with the command *mingw32-make*.

I followed the instruction recommended here [Instruction for building OpenCV for QT SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881913/how-to-link-opencv-in-qtcreator-and-use-qt-library). One of my friend got it worked before, but I don't know why it keeps getting build errors for me.

I'm really looking for the correct fix soon since I couldn't make any progress with this one.

Comment: It can't find the directory `C:/opencv2.4.12/opencv/sources/modules/highgui/`. Is it there?

Comment: @Velkan, it's physically existed in the directory, but I don't know why the build error says the _highgui_ module is not found.

Comment: In my case it searches for `modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all`, What i have here is `modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src`