# Build OpenCV using qmake

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qt-creator, qmake

- I make part of a 'big' project based on QT-Creator.
- It is an image adquisition/processing project.
- I am working in a particular library where we need to use OpenCV functions.
- I found out how to build, install and include OpenCV using **CMAKE** thanks to answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881913/how-to-link-opencv-in-qtcreator-and-use-qt-library).

**My problem** is that we need that each person on the team can get the OpenCV source and build/install/include automatically (something we normally do with our own libraries) **AND** this is 100% based on **qmake** then I should **not add CMAKE** to our project.

**The question is** does someone know how to build OpenCV directly with **qmake** in a project on QT-Creator?

Comment: Whoa... wait. Don't you want to add OpenCV _sources_ into your project, do you? QMake is fine, you can build OpenCV *once* with all the 100500 configuration flags, get lib/dll/so files + include headers, put all of that in some project folder, like "/thirdParty/", then any developer would add that dependency in the pro-file. It looks better than rebuilding the enormous OpenCV sources with your project every time. 
Could that approach fit your needs?

Comment: I know, I also feel it's too complicated, I'm wondering if I can build it using CMAKE on QT-creator

Comment: 1) You can, Qt Creator supports qmake, you'll have to deal with flags almost manually though 2) If you just want to make the build process of OpenCV less complicated, *cmake-gui* would suit you best, IMHO. It would be as simple as "open folder, select destination dir, select flags with mouse, run configure", try it!