# Undefined reference errors in Qt Creator | OpenCV

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I linked OpenCV to Qt Creator with the help of [this](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_setup_Qt_and_openCV_on_Windows) guide. However while compiling a simple code to read and display the image, I am getting undefined reference errors.

`test.pro`

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = opencvtest
TEMPLATE = app
# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += D:\opencv\build\include

LIBS += D:\opencv-build\bin\libopencv_core320.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv-build\bin\libopencv_highgui320.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv-build\bin\libopencv_imgcodecs320.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv-build\bin\libopencv_imgproc320.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv-build\bin\libopencv_features2d320.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv-build\bin\libopencv_calib3d320.dll


# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

`mainwindow.cpp`

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("img101.jpg", 1);
       cv::namedWindow("My Image");
       cv::imshow("My Image", image);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

[These are the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ey17q.png) I am getting while building the file.
Using Windows 10, MinGW 7.3.0 32-bit C and C++ compiler.

Comment: You can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881913/how-to-link-opencv-in-qtcreator-and-use-qt-library

Comment: I think adding the *.dll files to LIBS is not sufficient here. Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718447/adding-external-library-into-qt-creator-project

Comment: Thanks, I have tried the both the methods mentioned (although I have already tried the one @KimKulling linked). Unfortunately I am not able to use OpenCV functions in Qt. Both the methods give the exact same error as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is working now. Apparently I had to link the libraries by right-clicking on the project folder on the left-sidebar, selecting Add Libraries and choosing the External Libraries option (*added one by one*).

```
win32: LIBS += -LD:/opencv-build/install/x86/mingw/lib/ -llibopencv_core320.dll
win32: LIBS += -LD:/opencv-build/install/x86/mingw/lib/ -llibopencv_highgui320.dll
win32: LIBS += -LD:/opencv-build/install/x86/mingw/lib/ -llibopencv_imgcodecs320.dll 
INCLUDEPATH += D:/opencv-build/install/include
DEPENDPATH += D:/opencv-build/install/include

////NOTE: imgcodecs library is required for imread to work//////
```

*References:*

[`imread`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) OpenCV docs

[`imgcodecs and imread`](https://answers.opencv.org/question/232639/undefined-reference-to-opencv_3410-on-ubuntu-1804/) post